# Node.js fs.watchFile persistent watch mechanics?

Tags: node.js

Can someone explain how persistent watch works?

Does it eat some resources on the PC if it is watching file(s) for changes?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`fs.watchFile` creates a `StatWatcher` which then performs a `stat` on the file that's being watched. How exactly that happens at the low level (besided doing the obvious stats call) is dependent on the event loop implementation with which node was compiled.

So yes, it takes up a bit of CPU, but at you can't do anything else besides polling here, that is, unless the underlying file system itself would issue the file change events.

See:
https://github.com/ry/node/blob/v0.3.2/lib/fs.js#L472
https://github.com/ry/node/blob/v0.3.2/src/node_stat_watcher.h#L39
https://github.com/ry/node/blob/v0.3.2/src/node_stat_watcher.cc#L78

#### Some more info on the parameters

> Interval is relavent where inotify is not available - it determines
>   how long to poll for updates.
>   Persistent has to do with how the program should act when nothing but
>   watchFile is running. The default is to exit.
>
> > As far as I saw, it takes 3--5 seconds to notice the changes (with the
> >     default settings), can i make it faster?
>
> On linux it uses inotify - which is faster
>
> > how heavy is watching hundreds of files?
>
> Heavy. It's not meant for that.

Source: Post on the [Node.js Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/98939a501b98fdb8?tvc=2) by Ryan Dahl

**In conclusion**
If you're on linux, the `interval` option has no effect et all.
If you don't set `persistent` and there's nothing else in the event loop besides the file watcher, the program will exit.

Comment: So better to set manual polling than setting persistent watch?

Comment: The persistent parameter does not effect anything about the watching itself. If you **don't** set it, the program will exit when the only callback that's left in the event loop is watching the file. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ivo, just as a heads up I have referenced your answer in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567457/nodejs-how-would-one-watch-a-large-amount-of-files-folders-on-the-server-side-fo