# Monitor changes of remote file without downloading it with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, monitoring

Is there a possibility to monitor changes of file on some server without downloading it?
I read about chokidar module but I cant find anything about my issue
I believe there is the way to watch some headers or smth like this
Maybe here is someone who have solved similar issue?

Comment: Your file is in the same server as your NodeJS app ?

Comment: @MohamedAmjadLASRI No its "somewhere"

Comment: Even if you watch just headers you're still downloading it, or at least some part of it. And then to check for changes, you'll have to store the previous content to compare it against.

Comment: chowkidar or other file watchers are simply wrappers for node's core [fs.filewatch](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) and [the way it works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394620/node-js-how-does-fs-watchfile-work) doesn't apply to remote files

Answer (score 1):

You can check Last-Modified and/or E-tag http headers.

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {method: 'HEAD', host: 'stackoverflow.com', port: 80, path: '/'};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log(res.headers);
  }
);
req.end();
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can "watch" files using NodeJS.

**How to do it:**

There is several NodeJS modules allowing that. Take a look at [watchr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watchr) for example. You can "watch" a file or a directory using it.