# NodeJS: How would one watch a large amount of files/folders on the server side for updates?

Tags: search, filesystems, node.js

I am working on a small NodeJS application that essentially serves as a browser based desktop search for a LAN based server that multiples users can query. The users on the LAN all have access to a shared folder on that server and are traditionally used to just placing files within that folder to sharing among everyone, and I want to keep that process the same.

The first solution I came across was the [fs.watchFile](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html) which has been touched on in other stackoverflow questions. In the first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482352/node-js-fs-watchfile-persistent-watch-mechanics) user [Ivo Wetzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170224/ivo-wetzel) noted that on a linux system fs.watchFile uses inotify but, was of the opinion that fs.watchFile should not be used for large amounts of files/folders.

In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394620/node-js-how-does-fs-watchfile-work) about fs.watchFile user [tjameson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/538551/tjameson) first reiterated that on Linux inotify would be used by fs.fileWatch and recommended to just use a combination of [node-inotify-plusplus](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-inotify-plusplus) and [node-walk](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-walk) but again stated this method should not be used for a large number of files. With a comment and response he suggested only watching the modified times of directories and then rescanning the relevant directory for file changes.

My biggest hurdles seem to be that even with tjameson's suggestion there is still a hard limit to the number of folders monitored (of which there are many and growing). Also it would have to be done recursively because the directory tree is somewhat deep and can also be subject to change at the lower branches so I would have to monitor the following at every folder level (or alternatively monitor the modified time of the folders and then scan to find out what happened):

- creation of file or subfolder
- deletion of file or subfolder
- move of file or subfolder
- deletion of self
- move of self

Assuming the inotify has limits in line with what was said above then this alone to me seems like it may be too many monitors when I have a significant amount of nested subfolders. The real awesome way looks like it would involve [kqueue](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man2/kqueue.2.html) which I subsequently found as a topic of discussion on a better fs.fileWatch in a [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs-dev/browse_thread/thread/29e6a7733f254795).

It seems clear to me that keeping a database of the relevant file and folder information is the appropriate course of action on the query side of things, but keeping that database synchronized with the actual state of the file system under the directories of concern will be the challenge.

So what does the community think? Is there a better or well known solution for attacking this problem that I am just unaware of? Is it best just to watch all directories of interest for a single change e.g. modified time and then scan to find out what happened? Is it better to watch all the relevant inotify alerts and modify the database appropriately? Is this not a problem which is solvable by a peasant like me?

Comment: How many are we talking?

Comment: Currently the are about 1000 top directories with maybe another 2000 directories beneath these at up to 5 levels deep. This will only expand over time and I could easily see it getting past the 8192 mark you had mentioned in the other post.

Comment: So I'm guessing these fancy new native file events don't bubble to upper directories then.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).  I use it to monitor files for changes in my dev environment and restart my node processes when relevant project files change.

Comment: Seems like a decent options but I think I'd really like to stay with a pure node solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look at the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs).

I implemented something similar with ruby on the client side and nodejs on the server side.
The best approach is to keep hashes to check if the files or folders changed.

Comment: Many of the files are quite large and speed is the reason we are using a locally networked drive so for this application the dropbox API probably wouldn't fit, although it certainly stirs up other ideas that I will have to store for now.

Comment: As far as the hashes, maybe I'm confused, but it seems like that would not solve the issue at hand. I'd still need to run a hashing function on the files and folders at a rate similar to just polling the files themselves, to detect any changes.